# Get uid after anonymously signing in using AngularFire2 AngularFireAuth

Tags: firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Sign in works, however when I try to access the uid, it comes back null. I've seen the uid in console. I just can't seem to get it out of my service. Here are the relevant parts of my AuthService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  uid: any = null;
  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {    
    this._firebaseAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.uid = user.uid;
      }
    });
  signInAnonymously() {
    return this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
  });
}
```

In my component, I call signInAnonymously() on a button click:

```
onGuestClick() {
  let uid: any = null;
  const guestSignIn = this.authService.signInAnonymously().then(() => {
    uid = this.authService.uid;
    console.log(uid);  // returns null
    this.toggleOnline(uid);
  });
}
```

Auth state is changing, but my uid isn't being updated, or at least not before I call for it.  Do I need to call on AuthStateChanged somewhere other than my service constructor? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to print uid in onAuthStateChange listener after this line: this.uid = user.uid;

Comment: I solved this by moving the toggleonline function to a my auth service and out of the component.

Comment: Not quite familiar with Angular but "this.uid = user.uid" seems to be suspicious to me. The this reference in the callback listen could point to sth else rather than your AuthService object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving the function that needed the id from the component and into the auth service where access to the id was working.